# python list of hex numbers to string and write to file?

Tags: python, string, file, list, hex

I have a list of hex numbers I need to convert to string to write it to binary file. How can I do that? (convert the list of hex numbers to a string)

Answer (score 9):

converting to a string is easy

```
>>> "aabbccddeeff".decode('hex')
'\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff'
```

you don't need to do anything special to write this to a file

```
>>> with open("out.txt", "wb") as f:
...     f.write("aabbccddeeff".encode('hex'))
```

For Python3, it is slightly different

```
>>> import binascii
>>> with open("out.txt", "wb") as f:
...     f.write(binascii.unhexlify("aabbccddeeff"))
... 
6
```

**Edit** after clarification in the comments:

```
>>> with open("out.txt", "wb") as f:
...     f.write(''.join(['\x00', '\x80', '\xfe', '\x7f']))
```

Again, this is slightly different in Python3

```
>>> with open("out.txt", "wb") as f:
...     f.write(b''.join([b'\x00', b'\x80', b'\xfe', b'\x7f']))
... 
4
```

Comment: I would call the inclusion of the `b` flag in writing something special.

Comment: Sorry if I'm mistaken, but it seems like you are converting an ASCII string to hex string, but I need to convert a list of hex numbers to a string (without the commas and all that)

Comment: @b7512427, could you add an example to your question?

Comment: ...`{', '0x00', '\x80', '\xfe', '\x7f', '\x00', '\xe5', '\x00', '\x19', '\xfc', '\x7
f', '}', '\x8d', '\xbf', '\xc6', '\xb9', '\xb0', '\xab', '\xc4', '0x00', '\xdb',
 '\xd9', '\xdc', '\xd6', '\x92', '_', 'w', 'x', 'h', '[', '\\', 'o', '}', '\xb1'
, '\xb9', '\xad', '\x9c', '\x8c', 'v', '{', '0x00', '\xfd', '\x7f', '\x00', '\xe...`

Comment: @b7512427, ok that looks more like a list of 1-character strings, let me fix my answer

Comment: I was mistaken I guess. Im reading it from a binary file and using struct.unpack('<c', file.read(1)). Thats what I store in the list. And after some processing, I need to store the data (from the list) in another binary file.